# Obtaining values out of XML using Where clause

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Good Evening!  I have a multi-level XML file that I need to extract some data out of and then spit it back out in a CSV file.  I have been struggling with the extracting the specific data that I need.  I have gotten my XML query to the point of where I get the data returned that I need, but I am unsure of how to get the specific pieces of data I need out of the data in question.

What I need out of the below as my end result is the following...

For each person node, I need to identify the following pieces of data and record them to create the export file. This would run in a foreach loop over a large number of person records

var emailAddress - This is user + ‘@’ + registry where association == type “ 2”
I.E. testuser@domain.tld

var alias - The next part is the alias  – That comes from within the person node and is user where association == type “1”
I.E. test1

var servername - The last part to be extracted is the servername which is inside that same person tag and is registry in association where type == “1”
I.E. servername.fqdn

I will then be using a StringBuilder to join all of these on every foreach to give the desired output.

I will not know the domain name or server name prior to the execution of the tools on the file.  It could also vary within the file, hence why these are not simply hardcoded.

My current code returns the full association information below.

I greatly appreciate ANY assistance.  I have learned a ton from here, and greatly appreciate all of you.

My XML file looks like

```
<eim server="servername" timestamp="1489506332830">
 <domain name="domainname" description="domainanme">
  <registry name="servername" type="2342.52342.123-caseIgnore" kind="1" description="Created by wizard.">
   <alias type="Other">passwordMap=false</alias>
   <alias type="DnsHostName">servername</alias>
  </registry>
  <registry name="domainanme" type="2342.52342.123-caseIgnore" kind="1" description="Created by wizard.">
   <alias type="KerberosRealm">domainnamee</alias>
   <alias type="Other">passwordMap=false</alias>
  </registry>
  <person name="tuser" description="Test User">
   <association type="1" registry="servername.fqdn" user="test1"/>
   <association type="2" registry="domainname.tld" user="testuser"/>
  </person>
  <person name="tuser2" description="Test User2">
   <association type="1" registry="servername.fqdn" user="test2"/>
   <association type="2" registry="domainname.tld" user="testuser2"/>
  </person>
```

My current code is

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("c:\\temp\\eimexport.eiml");

        List<string> testing = new List<string>();
        XmlElement eimElement = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList eimNodes = eimElement.SelectNodes("/eim/domain/person");

        foreach (XmlNode parseEimNode in eimNodes)
        {

            testing.Add(parseEimNode.InnerXml);

        }


        foreach (var s in testing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `XmlDocument`, filtering can be done using XPath predicate expression (expression in `[]`) :

```
foreach (XmlNode parseEimNode in eimNodes)
{
    var email = parseEimNode.SelectSingleNode("association[@type=2]");
    var user = email.GetAttribute("user");
    var domain = email.GetAttribute("registry");

    var server = parseEimNode.SelectSingleNode("association[@type=1]");
    var _alias = server.GetAttribute("user");
    var servername = server.GetAttribute("registry");

    // process all information gathered so far accordingly

}
```

Comment: I had to make a slight change, but this got me on the right track!
I needed to do 
` email.Attributes["user"].Value;`  And so on instead of GetAttributes.  Thank You so much!